# Replacing matrix elements Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

Matlab-I have created a matrix that is over 100,000 rows and three columns
I want to be able to write a code that will go through the values in the third column and if they are outside a specified range replace that value with the average of it's neighbors. I tried to input this to see if I could reference the correct values in my matrix

```
run5((run5(:,3)>.002) | (run5(:,3)<0),3) = []
```

but all I got was
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

And I have no idea how to go about the averaging
Any help would be appreciated

First 6 lines

> -2.76800000000000 8.09400000000000    0.000894000000000000
>
> -2.76800000000000 7.84400000000000    0.000929000000000000
>
> -2.76800000000000 7.59400000000000    0.00101500000000000
>
> -2.76800000000000 7.34400000000000    0.000747000000000000
>
> -2.76800000000000 7.09400000000000    0.00103900000000000
>
> -2.76800000000000 6.84400000000000    0.000888000000000000
>
> -2.76800000000000 6.59400000000000    0.000828000000000000
>
> -2.76800000000000 6.34400000000000    0.000737000000000000
>
> -2.76800000000000 6.09400000000000    -0.000858000000000000
>
> -2.76800000000000 5.84400000000000    0.000723000000000000

Comment: Please add few rows of your matrix

Comment: I added them into my question. Is this enough or do you need more?

Comment: run5((run5(:,3)>.002) | (run5(:,3)<0),3) = [1] This will replace all the values outside the range i dont want with ones but I need to know how to do something other than 1                         Also this is Matlab

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the command line tool awk, not sure what language you are trying to use in your question. Is this what you want?

```
awk '{if($3 > 0.002 || $3 < 0){ $3=$1+$2/2; print;} else print}' test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're doing this in Matlab?  If so, please add tag. Perhaps this will help

```
> r = rand(100,3);              % random input matrix
> i = r(:,3)>0.4 & r(:,3)<0.5;  % row indices where 3rd column value between 0.4 and 0.5
> r(i,3)=0;                     % for those rows set the column three value to zero
> sum(r(:,3)==0)                %count zeros

ans =

    12
```

If you want to modify the values based on neighboring rows.  You can do the following

```
    > r = rand(100,3);              % random input matrix
    > i = r(:,3)>0.4 & r(:,3)<0.5;  % row indices where 3rd column value between 0.4 and 0.5
    > ind = find(i);                % row index values
    > r(ind,3) = r(ind-1,:) + r(ind+1,:);  % sum of previous and next row
```

Of course, you should check the boundary conditions for the first and last rows.

Comment: Thank you after looking at your code I was able to solve my problem

Comment: @AlisonH. - The proper practice here is to accept the answer that helped you if you no longer need help.  That's done by clicking on the checkmark icon at the top left of the post that helped you.  The checkmark is located just to the left at the top, below the up and down voting buttons.